# Is it possible to label cells in arrays?

Tags: fortran

Is it possible to assign labels for cells in arrays? I am just experimenting with arrays and I was curious if you could label different cells with descriptors. There is a diagram below for the kind of thing I wish to achieve-
[image: Matrix labelling]

Comment: Array indexes are always ingegers. But you can have integer named constants or some dictionary that translates character strings to integers (with some cost when searching the dictionary). Are you interested in these approaches?

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I am looking for... How would I go about this?

Comment: I do not have a time to answer now, but someone else might describe this kind of approach. It is quite generic.

Comment: All good! If someone doesn't answer I can probably find it online. Thanks for suggesting it!

Comment: What you are searching for as known in the programming community as an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) which provides _key,value_ pairs. While it is named an _array_, it is most of the time implemented as a binary tree or hash-table. Sadly, they are not a part of the Fortran Standard, but it is possible to make your own implementation of this in Fortran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are always indexed with integer indexes.

If the meaning of the rows and columns is constant and known at compile-time, you can have integer constants,that have the desired name and the value of the index, e.g.,

```
integer, parameter :: Plant1 = 1, Plant2 = 2,...
integer, parameter :: Day1 = 1, Day2 = 2,...

Array(Plant2, Day2) = 92
```

If this is not constant and and can be different every time you run your program for different data, you could certainly have an array of labels

```
character(label_len), allocatable :: rows(:)

rows = [character(label_len) :: "Plant 1", "Plant 2",...]
```

but you cannot use this for indexing. To find out which integer index corresponds to "Plant 2" you would have to search the array. This can be slow.

There is a data structure called [dictionary](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Paper_1/Fundamentals_of_data_structures/Dictionaries) that is used to retrieve such data assigned to character string labels more efficiently (still it takes some time). There are some Fortran implementations at https://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Hash+tables and hopefully one will also be developed for [stdlib](https://github.com/fortran-lang/stdlib/issues/1).